# How to view analytics on a google form by changing the link?

Tags: google-forms

I have heard that it is possible to view the analytics of a google form by changing the last part of the url to “analytics” but i heard this a long time ago and i don’t know what is going on because this time it didn't work.If someone can tell me how to do this it would be awesome.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 8):

You need to add the view word, which is `.../viewanalytics`

Comment: Note: this doesn't work if the publisher of the form hasn't published the analytics

Answer (score -1):

You will have to add your google analytics snippet to one of the webpages and then use the redirection. A simpler way will be to use https://www.trackyourform.com you can get a link from here, for which you can see analytics in your google accounts.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34697752)